# docker-compose caches run results

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having an issue with docker-compose where I'm passing a file into the container when it's run. The issue is that it doesn't seem to recognize when the file has been changed and serves the saved result back indefinitely until I change the name of the file.

An example (modified names for brevity):

```
jono@macbook:~/myProj% docker-compose run vpn conf.opvn 
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in conf.opvn:71: AXswRE+
5aN64mYiPSatOACC6+bISv8RcDPX/lMYdLwe8zQY6qWtbrjFXrp2 (2.3.8)
```

Then I change the file, save it, and run the command again - exact same output.

Then without changing anything I do this:

```
jono@macbook:~/myProj% cp conf.opvn newconf.opvn
```

And when I run `$ docker-compose run vpn newconf.opvn` it works. Seems really silly.

I'm working with Tmux and Mac if there is some way that affects it. Is this the expected behaviour? I couldn't find anything documenting this on the [docker-compose homepage](https://docs.docker.com/compose/).

**EDIT:**
Specifically I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/jfrazelle/dockerfiles/tree/master/openvpn) from the amazing Jess.

Comment: We're going to need to see your `docker-compose.yml` and possibly also your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Done. I added the repo link to the compose and docker file. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you are using is using `volume` in order to mount your current directory. Basically the file `conf.opvn` is copied to the docker container. 
When you change the file, the container doesn't see that change, but it does pick up the rename (which the container sees as a new file). This most probably is due to user rights of the file and the user rights of the folder in the docker container where this file is mounted. Try changing the file's permissions to 777 before beginning the process and check again.

You can find a discussion about this in the [official forum of docker](https://forums.docker.com/t/modify-a-file-which-mount-as-a-data-volume-but-it-didnt-change-in-container/2813/5)